# Image shows up as a small block while using xampp in netbeans editor

Tags: php, xampp, netbeans-8

Image doesnt show up properly.Only shows up a small block(not the actual image I want).It shows correct file path but does not load the actual image. Please suggest how to I display images in php projects using netbeans and xampp

Comment: <img id="img1" src="C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject\Images\imagename.jpg" style="display:none">

Comment: Basically I am trying to add images to my php page which change after a fixed interval of time which am implementing using javascript. Do I need to activate something in the netbeans editor to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Copied the code into notepad and placed the file in htdocs folder and opened it in the netbeans editor and it worked.